# How to get current pages menu text?

Tags: menus, walker

Is there an easy way of outputting the current pages menu text?

I am looking for something like

```
 <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

But for the current pages menu text.

Comment: Where are you wanting to output that menu text? Within the page template? Within the Menu Walker? More details please :)

Comment: I plan on outputting it in the widget text, which I made to accept php. I need to work around a cool comercial theme/plugin, so am forced to do ugly things like that.

Comment: If you're using a commercial theme, start off be creating a child theme (off topic, but best-practice and it will save you if there are any updates in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a Menu's entire item list with [wp_get_nav_menu_items()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items). Then, loop through them all and test against the current post_id, and voila, you have all your data.

```
<?php
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'main-menu' );
foreach( $menu_items as $item ) {
    print_r( $item ) ; // see what you can work with
    // carry on
}
```

Comment: if I paste it like that it should output all items correct? But it doesn't output anythng

Comment: ah i got the name wrong.

Comment: I just put in an example menu. The menu name will change depending on the theme you use.

Comment: Now once you see what exactly is in a menu_item object, you can see where the post ID matches up.. chances are it will be in the `parent` property

Comment: I found this ...WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 74... in the output. So now i need to check against it, like if(current post id = [ID]) display [title] or something like that?

Comment: exactly. in pseudo code it would be `if( current_post_id == $menu_item->parent) { // this menu item is the current post/page }`. It won't be ID, that is a unique ID for the menu item itself. Look for a match between your current post's ID and try to find it in that WP_Post Object.